# Call to a variable that is inside another function

Tags: python

```
def HOME():
    """ The first screen
    """

    print ('Welcome to my program!')
    input_grocery_list = input('Hello, please enter here a list of groceries: ')

    def input_to_list():
        """ This f takes the input 
        and put it inside a list 
        without the: ','
        and print the list
        """
        new_grocery_list = []
        separator = ", "
        while ',' in input_grocery_list:
            d = input_grocery_list.index(',') 
            y = input_grocery_list[:d]
            new_grocery_list.append(y)
            input_grocery_list = input_grocery_list[(d+1):]
            if ',' not in input_grocery_list:
                new_grocery_list.append(input_grocery_list)
        print(separator.join(new_grocery_list))


    def the_groceries_list():
        """ Do somthing  to the first input
        accord to the next choice
        """

        print("You can chose a number betwen 1 - 9 n/ and we do the rest..")
        grocery_list = input('please enter here your choice : ') 
        if grocery_list == '1':
            input_to_list(input_grocery_list)

    if len(input_grocery_list) != 0:
        the_groceries_list()
HOME()
```

The error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 37, in HOME
  File "<stdin>", line 34, in the_groceries_list
TypeError: input_to_list() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

My problem is probably in the second function called "**input_to_list ()**"

While I am trying to read / change the "**input_grocery_list**" variable that is inside the first function (*HOME*)
It does not recognize him.

I tried to fix it using ***global*** or ***self*** but I probably don't really know where exactly to put them because in the meantime it didn't work for me.

Anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: You can't access functions'  local variables from outside of it. If you want to pass information between functions, use return values... Consider reading about functions in the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions)

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, you try to have a main function, but you should use a class instead of a function, so more like this.

```
class Home():
    def __init__(self):
        """
        define your class wide variables here as following
        """
        # example
        # self.your_name = 'hello'
        # to access it in an function IN this class, type: self.your_name
        pass

    def get_items(self):
        print('Welcome to my program!')
        input_grocery_list = input('Hello, please enter here a list of groceries (sep with comma): ')
        self.input_to_list(input_grocery_list)

    #                       you forgot this
    #                               ||
    #                               \/
    def input_to_list(self, grocery_list: str):
        """ This f takes the input
        and put it inside a list
        without the: ','
        and print the list
        """
        new_grocery_list = grocery_list.split(',')
        # to print as list
        print(new_grocery_list)
        # to print every item in list
        for item in new_grocery_list:
            print(item)
        # print('List End') # if you want to

    # I don't really know what that is supposed to do, but whatever it is it wont
    """
    def the_groceries_list(self):
        # Do somthing  to the first input
        # accord to the next choice

        print("You can chose a number betwen 1 - 9 n/ and we do the rest..")
        grocery_list = input('please enter here your choice : ')
        if grocery_list == '1':
            input_to_list(input_grocery_list)

        if len(input_grocery_list) != 0:
            the_groceries_list()
    """


# to use this class and it's functions first create an object
home = Home()

# than call a function
home.get_items()
```

I wont go into details of Classes and Object [but here is a link for you](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_classes.asp).
Read this, it should explain the basics pretty good.

Comment: Actually this is not a good example of using a class. See [this interesting video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0)

Comment: @Tomerikoo yeah maybe it isn't but it's not my job to explain OOP, this is a 3 second google search. This should only make his not working script to work

Comment: I didn't expect you to explain OOP, I claimed that it is not necessary...

Answer (score 0):

You need to change definition of your nested function so it can take args:

```
def input_to_list(input_grocery_list):
```